# Apache changes ASCII character in javascript js file

Tags: apache

I have a javascript file where I have to define some strings containing the `≡` character (i.e. `charCode 8801`).
When this javascript file is served by an Apache server (in my case on Linux), such character is converted to something weird ('â‰¡'). When the same file is served by a different web server (e.g. Node Lite-server) no conversion is performed and everything works as expected.
Any suggestion on how to change Apache configuration in order to avoid this happen?

Thanks in advance

Enrico

Comment: Check the encoding of the source files.  UTF-8?

Comment: no charset is defined in the SCRIPT element, so I guess it is UTF-8

Comment: Check the HTTP headers when requesting the javascript file and report the `Content-Type` header

Comment: These are the headers registered by Chrome  `Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_ga=GA1.2.666348663.1458209278

User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36`

Answer (score 0):

The javascript file itself is actually encoded.  Make sure yours are `UTF-8 without BOM`.  Checking the encoding varies depending on your text editor.  Notepad++, for example, is set in the preferences:

[image]

Double check your encoding and your MIME type and make sure it is compatible with Apache.

Comment: I checked with `file -I` command (I am on Mac) and I get `text/x-c++; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Try saving as a javascript file instead of C++.  What text editor are you using?

Comment: I am using VisualStudioCode.